# VBA Command button to open Userform returns 1004 error

Tags: excel, vba, userform

In a excel project, I have a sheet with data, a userform that draws data from that sheet, and a sheet to paste userform data.

I created a button in the data sheet that **should** open the user form. For reference the name of my userform is UserForm1. I get a 424 error `Object required`when I click on the command button. I would appreciate any help or clarification, seems I am getting my classes/instances mixed up?

Code below:

```
Private Sub blocksSorter_Click()
     Load UserForm
     UserForm.Show
End Sub
```

The form itself is within the same VBA project and is the only form in the project. My UserForm1 code is looks generally like this:

```
Private Sub UserForm_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    code
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    code
End Sub
```

The form will only show if I do this, and change my UserCode subs to `UserForm1` from `UserForm`.

```
Private Sub blocksSorter_Click()
     Load UserForm1
     UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: `UserForm1.Show` is actually correct, so you can leave it like that. And you dont really need to Load it first.

Comment: But would I then have to change my sub?

`Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` to Private Sub UserForm1_Initialize()`?

Comment: No, the sub uses the class name... that's how it's supposed to work. I usually name my forms something like `frmTransfer` to avoid the confusion.

Comment: But without changing the subs, I get a `Application-defined or object-defined error` when clicking the button

Comment: You arent "showing" the class `UserForm`, you are showing an instance of the class called `UserForm1`

Comment: Where would I put the code to show the `UserForm`? Would that be under the command code or in my `UserForm` code?

Comment: it looks like you already know where to put it - `blocksSorter_Click` - using the instance name `UserForm1` and not the class name `UserForm`

Comment: Right so I've changed the code under blocksSorter_Click() to include `Load UserForm1` and `UserForm1.Show` but I am getting the 1004 error. Does it have anything to do with setting the subs public/private?

Comment: Then your form name must not be `UserForm1` = Did you accidentally name it `UserForm` thinking that's what you were supposed to do?

Comment: Under properties for my form, I have the name as `UserForm1`, my VBE window also shows `UserForm1(UserForm)`

Comment: @braX figured it out, I need to change the caption in the properties as well. Cheers and ty very much for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Even though my form name is UserForm1, I had the caption as something else. With the help of braX, I have the following:

```
Private Sub blocksSorter_Click()
     Load UserForm1
     UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

My form properties are now as follows:

```
Name: UserForm1
Caption: UserForm1
```

My UserForm code remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Start a new VBA project.

Add a form.

Name the form `frmOne`

Double click on the form and add `MsgBox "Hello"` to that event.

Add another form.

Name that form `frmTwo`

Double click on the 2nd form and add `frmOne.Show` to that event.

Run the second form, and click on it, it should open frmOne. Then click on the frmOne and the msgbox should come up.

Notice that each form has a subroutine called `UserForm_Click()` but they are different. Does that help clear it up? I'm not sure how else to explain it to you.